# Python saying string index is out of range when I verified that it isn't

Tags: python, string, indexing, string-length, indexoutofrangeexception

So I'm making this program to display the positions of a substring in a string. I have the tuples working properly now (I hope), but for some reason python's giving me an error saying my index is out of range:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 11, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

But as you can see, I already verified it with len right before it evaluates the indexing:

```
sentence = "one two three one four one"
word = "one"

tracked = ()
n = 0
p = 0
for c in sentence:
    if n == 0 and c == word[n]:
        n += 1
        tracked = (p,)
    elif n == len(word) and c == word[n]: #Line 11 is right here
        print(tracked[0], tracked[1])
        tracked = ()
        n = 0
    elif c == word[n]:
        n += 1
        tracked = (tracked[0], p)
    else:
        tracked = ()
        n = 0
    p += 1
```

My apologies if this is another stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: Your error is not on line 11 in your file.  Post the whole file so your error message matches the correct line.

Comment: @mikeb This is the whole script

Comment: #Line 11  word[n] is always word[len(word)] but last index is always len[word]-1

Comment: Try put a `print(n)` below `for c in sentence:`, and see why you get `string index out of range` at `c == word[n]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexing starts from 0, you need to use

```
elif n == len(word) and c == word[n - 1]:
```

Comment: Actually I needed ```n == len(word)-1``` but thanks :)

Comment: And with another small edit I finally finished my script and it's working great. Thanks :D Will be accepting in 3 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Python are zero indexed.  There fore if you have:

```
a = "Some String"
n = len(a)
a[n]
```

This is invalid, since the only valid indexes of a are [0:n-1]

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because c == word[n] goes out of range.

Arrays are always indexed beginning with 0, therefore this should do the trick:

```
c == word[n - 1]
```